# Bind event to multiple elements without looping (vanilla JS)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to achieve the equivalent of:

```
$('div').on('click', function() {
    // Do something
});
```

But without jQuery.  My initial thought was to use a `for` loop to iterate over all elements in the set, but my guess is there's a better way of achieving this without using a loop (some native method?).

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

function someEvent() { // Generic function to test against
    alert('event fired');
}

for (var i=0, j = elems.length; i < j; i += 1) {
    elems[i].addEventListener("click", someEvent);
}
```

Is there a more elegant way of doing this without the inclusion of a library?

Comment: I think it's either that or binding the event to an parent element that contains all the desired elements (ex. body) and using the `target` property in the event.

Comment: You have to loop or delegate, but of course you can write your own wrapper function so that you don't have to repeat looping code all over your scripts every time you need to do this. Note that jQuery's `.on()` method loops internally.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you want is [event delegation](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate). It works by binding a single event to a parent of multiple nodes, and analyzing the event's target node. For example, you can bind `onmouseup` to the `body` node, and when it is triggered from releasing the mouse on a `div` node, the `body` event object will contain that `div` in the `target` property. You can analyze the target to make sure it matches certain criterias.

A better way to explain this, is to just provide a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/gn29N/).

```
document.body.onmouseup = function (event) {
    var target = event.target || event.toElement;

    if (target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "div") {
       alert(target.childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    };
};
```

The main point of interest with this example is the `target` variable, and the condition to verify that our `target` is a `div`. The condition can even be a `className` or anything your heart desires.